Class not found when using 'aar' file as dependency
I have created a plugin library where I am using external dependencies like firebase, androidx.
For testing I build the .aar file and import it in sample app using:
implementation files('../libs/scannerlib-release.aar')

as soon as I ran the app, the app crashed with the message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/LocalViewModelStoreOwner;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.LocalViewModelStoreOwner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/one.zoop.sample.scanner-PScmi1qx4Ew1MI-h6qmZXw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/one.zoop.sample.scanner-PScmi1qx4Ew1MI-h6qmZXw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/one.zoop.sample.scanner-PScmi1qx4Ew1MI-h6qmZXw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]

Why this is happening so? Do we need to mention the library dependencies again in sample app to make it run?
I wanted to include the library along with dependency like a maven dependency in single line do locally.

Some time ago in my app I used the absolute file path (e.g. implementation files('C:/AndroidStudioProjects/VoiceRecognitionLibrary/app/build/outputs/aar/voicerecognitionlibrary.aar') )

tried absolute path didn't work too.

The aar file doesn't contain the transitive dependencies and doesn't have a pom file which describes the dependencies used by the module.
It means that, if you are importing a aar file using a flatDir repository you have to specify the dependencies also in your project.
You should use a Maven repository, private or public, to avoid the issue. In this case, Gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.
Here's how can you do it:
https://medium.com/prismapp/publishing-android-library-to-bintray-ba588184b690

If you are adding your dependencies as implementation(...) they are internal and exclusive to the component they are declared in, in this case scannerlib-release.aar.
You could try declaring the dependencies you want to be available to the consumer of your aar lib using api(...).

Dependencies appearing in the api configurations will be transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will appear on the compile classpath of consumers. Dependencies found in the implementation configuration will, on the other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into the consumers' compile classpath.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

Not working ,I have some external dependencies used in module library.
and as per my searches ,arr doesn't include dependencies used in library.
So either i need to use local maven or include all dependencies in main project again
